# Query IMPORTRANGE is only pulling the first row of data

Tags: google-sheets

```
=Query(IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ydrIKPJkYdHa3fJk7NYtGkrMZwU1RyPmOfjt037Ekwk/edit?usp=sharing", "ATJ!A:Z"), "SELECT Col2,Col5,Col6,Col8,Col10,Col11,Col12 WHERE Col5 contains 'Cat Wilson' ORDER BY Col2")
```

this is only giving me the header row, any suggestions? I need a specific name to filter into Col5. Still very new to this so any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

hard to tell from insufficient intel you provided... try:

```
=QUERY({IMPORTRANGE("1ydrIKPJkYdHa3fJk7NYtGkrMZwU1RyPmOfjt037Ekwk", "ATJ!A:Z")}, 
 "select Col2,Col5,Col6,Col8,Col10,Col11,Col12 
  where lower(Col5) contains 'cat wilson' 
  order by Col2 asc", 1)
```